# How can I get jQuery to toggle a class with fadeToggle?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using `fadeToggle()` to toggle between the visibilty of the chosen elements. When my page is loaded, all the given elements are given the class 'invisible' (which gives them the CSS property `display: none;`).

I want to be able to toggle this class name, because another function I use to toggle the visibility/invisiblity of all the elements requires it to be able to find elements with the property invisible.

This is my current code:

```
  var sections = $('.ovelseSeksjon');
  var title = sections.find("h1")
  var assignments = sections.find(".ovelseInnhold");
  var plusMinus = sections.find(".fa");
  var toggleAll = $("#mainText").find(".toggleall");

  // Hide all assignments at page load
  assignments.addClass("invisible");

  // Toggle the invisible class when the title is clicked
  title.on('click', function() {
    // To capture the scope of this, it will be something else in setTimeout.
    $(this).parent().find(".invisible").fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
  });

  toggleAll.on("click", function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("class"));
    if($(this).hasClass("open")) {
      assignments.filter(".invisible").removeClass("invisible");
    }
    if($(this).hasClass("close")) {
      assignments.not(".invisible").addClass("invisible");
    }
  });
```

This works, but not in the way I want it to work. This simply adds a new CSS property `display: block`, that only overrides the previous invisibility value. The invisible class still remains. What can I do to achieve my desired effect? If there is no easy way to remove the invisible class, how can I update my toggleAll to work properly again? (It can't hide the elements. Even though it indeed removes the invisible property, the display: block is still there and it does not get removed by my toggleAll).

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your CSS?

Comment: The entirety of it? Or just the invisible class?
The invisible class is simply `display: none`.

Comment: It would be nice if you could add the relevant HTML and CSS, if you can create a working extract of your code as a snippet it's much easier to help.

Comment: The problem is that when you are targeting `.invisible` it's not there to target when you removed it the first time. So instead of `.find(".invisible").toggleFade(...` do this: `find(assignments).toggleFade(...` See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the right hierarchy for your HTML, but here an example.

Your assignment content (`.ovelseInnhold`) should start with `display:none`set via CSS.

```js
var sections = $('.ovelseSeksjon');
  var title = sections.find("h1")
  var assignments = sections.find(".ovelseInnhold");
  var plusMinus = sections.find(".fa");
  var toggleAll = $("#mainText").find(".toggleall");


  // Toggle the invisible class when the title is clicked
  title.on('click', function() {
    // To capture the scope of this, it will be something else in setTimeout.
    $(this).parent().find(".ovelseInnhold").fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
  });

  toggleAll.on("click", function() {
    $('.ovelseInnhold').fadeToggle("fast", "linear");
  });
```

```css
.ovelseInnhold { 
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="mainText">
  <div class="toggleall">Toggle All</div>
</div>


<section class="ovelseSeksjon">
  <h1>Title 1</h1>
  <div class="ovelseInnhold">
    Assignments
  </div>
</section>


<section class="ovelseSeksjon">
  <h1>Title 2</h1>
  <div class="ovelseInnhold">
    Assignments
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: How can I get toggleAll to work then? It will open all the elements, but can't close them, again because of the persistent display: block property the elements get.

Comment: Thanks! This was just what I was looking for! :D

Answer (score 1):

I started the HTML before you posted it so bear that in mind. The details are commented in the Snippet.

#### SNIPPET

```js
var txt = $('#mainText');
var sec = $('.section');
var hdr = $("h1");
var sub = $(".subSection");
var ico = $(".fa");
var all = $(".toggleAll");

sub.addClass("inv");

// Click a title to...
hdr.on('click', function() {
  
  /*
  |Select this title's siblings that follow afterwards
  |and switch their class between .inv and .vis
  */
  $(this).nextAll(sub).toggleClass('inv vis');
});

// Click the .toggleAll button...
all.on("click", function(e) {
  
  // Prevents anchor from jumping
  e.preventDefault();
  
  // Switch between plus and minus icons
  ico.toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus');
  
  //Switch `.toggleAll` classes
  $(this).toggleClass('close open');
  
  // if this button ends up with class .close...
  if ($(this).hasClass('close')) {
    
    // remove/add = classes .vis and .inv
    sub.removeClass('vis').addClass('inv');
  } 
  else {
    
    // else vice versa
    sub.removeClass('inv').addClass('vis');
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #999;
}
.vis {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  line-height: 1;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 500 linear;
  color: white;
  background: black;
}
.inv {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  width: 0;
  transition: all 500 linear;
}
.close {
  background: black;
  color: yellow;
  line-height: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}
.open {
  background: yellow;
  color: black;
  line-height: 3;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
h1,
section {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
.toggleAll {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<main id='mainText'>
  <a href='#/' class='toggleAll close'>
    <i class='fa fa-plus fa-2x'>ALL</i>
  </a>
  <section class='section'>
    <h1>I to IV</h1>
    <div class='subSection'>ONE</div>
    <div class='subSection'>TWO</div>
    <div class='subSection'>THREE</div>
    <div class='subSection'>FOUR</div>
  </section>
  <section class='section'>
    <h1>V to VIII</h1>
    <div class='subSection'>FIVE</div>
    <div class='subSection'>SIX</div>
    <div class='subSection'>SEVEN</div>
    <div class='subSection'>EIGHT</div>
  </section>
  <section class='section'>
    <h1>IX to XII</h1>
    <div class='subSection'>NINE</div>
    <div class='subSection'>TEN</div>
    <div class='subSection'>ELEVEN</div>
    <div class='subSection'>TWELVE</div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Oh, cool. Thanks!
Not really what I was looking for (that is, a ease in effect).
But I will use that plus/minus-icon solution, I didn't even think of that.
Sorry for not including the HTML/CSS, I went to bed shortly after posting this, haha

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you got something extra out of it. As a bonus: `<label for='config'><output id='config' class='fa fa-cog' onclick='this.classList.toggle("fa-spin")'></output>Settings</label>` it's plain JS, no jQ needed, but you'll still need the FA css of course.